# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f070016 type #0x3 is not valid

Tags: java, android

When I click on "trovamico" cardview to be able to go to that activity, it crashes and I get this error. Below I put the code of the Home and trovamicoActivity of my app.I tried to see on the site but could not find anything that helped me.If you need my github project let me know

Error

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f070016 type #0x3 is not valid
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDimensionPixelSize(Resources.java:827)
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.ax.d(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@221820084@22.18.20 (150700-0):5)
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.fe.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@221820084@22.18.20 (150700-0):6)
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.bj.aA(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@221820084@22.18.20 (150700-0):14)
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.cn.o(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@221820084@22.18.20 (150700-0):2)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.o.aY(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@221820084@22.18.20 (150700-0):26)
    at ej.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@221820084@22.18.20 (150700-0):4)
    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:1043)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zza.zzH(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.0.0:2)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzk.onCreateView(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.0.0:5)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.zzau.onCreateView(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.0.0:7)
    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zad.zab(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:2)
    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.zaf(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:1)
    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.onCreateView(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:2)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.0.0:1)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2995)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:523)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:261)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:113)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1374)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2841)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2784)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:262)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:478)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1435)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:8024)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3475)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
```

Home XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="7"
    android:background="#fafafa"
    tools:context="com.example.chatapp.Fragments.HomeFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@drawable/header_bg"
        android:padding="12dp"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Home"
            android:textColor="#fafafa"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Benvenuto"
            android:textColor="#fafafa"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            />

    </LinearLayout>


    <!--Creating the menu grid button-->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:padding="16dp"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:padding="16dp"
            >
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/trovamico"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:cardElevation="2dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    >
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_plus_one_24"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="  Trova un amico   "
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cercaincontro"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:cardElevation="2dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:clickable="true"
                >
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    >
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_plus_one_24"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Cerca un incontro"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:padding="16dp"
            >

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:cardElevation="2dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:clickable="true"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="335dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_plus_one_24" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Organizza un incontro"
                        android:textAlignment="center" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

TrovamicoActivity

```
public static final String TAG = "addreess";

//private GoogleMap mMap;
private FragmentsTrovamicoBinding binding;
LatLng latLng;


private DatabaseReference reference;
private FirebaseUser firebaseUser;

List<String> addresses, genders;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    binding = FragmentsTrovamicoBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());
    Log.d(TAG, "String addreess: " + addresses);
    addresses = new ArrayList<>();
    genders = new ArrayList<>();

    firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(firebaseUser.getUid());

  

    ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                reference.child("address").get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        String address = task.getResult().getValue().toString();
                        addresses.add(address);
                    }
                });
                Log.d(TAG, "String addreess: " + addresses);
                reference.child("gender").get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        String gender = task.getResult().getValue().toString();
                        genders.add(gender);
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    };

    reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    for (int i = 0; i < addresses.size(); i++) {
        String user_address = addresses.get(i);
        if (!user_address.equals("To be added")) {
            Log.d(TAG, "String addreess: " + addresses);
            String user_gender = genders.get(i);
            latLng = getLocationFromAddress(user_address);
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            markerOptions.position(latLng);
            markerOptions.title("You");
            Log.d(TAG, "String addreess: " + addresses);
            markerOptions.icon(BitmapFromVector(getApplicationContext(), (user_gender.equals("Male")) ? R.drawable.male : R.drawable.female));
            googleMap.clear();
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 5));
            googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        }
    }
}

public LatLng getLocationFromAddress(String strAddress) {

    Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(this);
    List<Address> address;
    LatLng p1;

    try {
        address = coder.getFromLocationName(strAddress, 5);
        if (address == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Address location = address.get(0);
        p1 = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

        return p1;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Post the code from `TrovamicoActivity`

Comment: Edited question, is a google maps activity

Comment: Upload the xml too where the CardView exist

Comment: Done, can you check?

Answer (score 10):

### In my case, I clear the cache on my emulator and re-run the app

[image]

Comment: I second this, or uninstalling and reinstalling would help as well

Comment: Thank you. It worked on first time after clearing cache. on second time it again crash. Then i have to clear the cache again

Answer (score 5):

I have solved this problem by copying the missing file into the drawable folder.

First you have to find the name of the missing resource. In the project window, open the generated apk file by double clicking which exists in the app/release folder. Click resources.arsc file and find the file with ID = 0x7f070016. So you will see the name of the resource file as abc_cab_background_top_material.xml

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/b19cba1/v7/appcompat/res/drawable/abc_cab_background_top_material.xml

Copy this file content and put under drawable folder. Then your app will find the needed resource file and does not crash.

Answer (score 0):

You have a resource problem.
An image may not be found in the drawable folder.

Copy xhdpi and other folders resources into default drawable folder.

Copy all the files that are in the drawable-......  folders to the drawble folder

Comment: What should I do? I have attached a screenshot  https://imgur.com/a/zQ6QDE9

Comment: @frongi Copy all the files that are in the drawable-...... folders to the drawble folder

Comment: A copy of all the files in the drawble .... folders must be in the drawble.  Some files may be duplicates. Replace them.  Before doing this, make a backup of the drawble folder so that you can go back if you have a problem. I hope this works.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/U1KjpZD this error appear when i try sto start the app, i have also replace but idk is this

Comment: I can't do replace because one is .png and one is .xml. What should I do now?

Comment: This is the problem that exists.  Each file that is placed in different drawable folders must be of the same type.  This means that if you have x.png in one folder, you should not have the x file with another type in other folders.
Delete one of theme

Comment: what are you even talking about? it's about Google Maps library, he can't control its resources, it seems just a wrong cache during building from Studio